# Proper definition of strong orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

I'm currently working through "An Introduction to Mathematical
Cryptography" by Hoffstein, Pipher and Silverman and I wonder how to cleanly define the term of "better" orthogonality of a basis $B$ of a lattice $L$.

> The **Hadamard-Ratio** of the Basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is: $$\mathcal{H}(B) = \left(\frac{\det(L)}{||v_1||\cdots||v_n||}\right)^{1/n} $$
>   $B$ is **strongly orthogonal** if $\mathcal{H}(B) \approx 1$.

The term $\mathcal{H}(B) \approx 1$ is a bit vague since in an example $\mathcal{H}(B) \approx 0.7$ is also considered relatively orthogonal.

Is there a way to define the term of relative orthogonality more cleanly in terms of typical calculus a la $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\mathcal{H}(B) = 1- \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon$ "small"?

Comment: $|H(B) - 1| < \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ "small"? However, this is equivalent, you will still have to answer the question if $0.3$ is considered small or not.

Comment: You want a binary decision or a smooth measure? The number is ensured to be on $[0,1]$ then if you want another smooth measure you can just remap it by your favourite non-linear monotonic remapping that preserves $0\to 0, 1\to 1$.

Comment: @Bemte Indeed, adding an epsilon didn't really improve the definition since the term "small" makes the definition look vague :(

Comment: @mathreadler In fact, I'd be just as happy with one of both outcomes since I just need a formalization of the term "strong orthogonality" for a presentation and I can't see the best approach to it.

Comment: A real number can carry more information than a binary value. Why do you want to throw that information away?

Comment: @mathreadler A real number itself might provide the same problem as mentioned above, is a value of $0.7$ now good or bad. With a binary decision the outcome is clear but you're right information would be lost.

Comment: You can not ask if it is "good" or "bad" without specifying for what purpose or application you aim it for.

Comment: I think depending on what you use $B$ for, different values are considered good or not so good. So you could say "we want (for our purposes) have $\epsilon = 0.1$, but there might still be other applications where everything works well for $\epsilon = 0.3$. It's just like saying an algorithm has "good performance", that also differs depending on who you ask.

Comment: @mathreadler The application is to determine whether or not a selected basis can be used to apply an algorithm and my lecturer told me to work on a formal definition but I guess it's not possible without fixed intervalls.

Comment: @Bemte Thank you for your answer, I guess the only solution is to just set certain boundaries and give them a meaning, just like you pointed out.

Comment: Then you need to try the algorithm and evaluate different nonlinear remappings of the measure until you find something that works well enough.